# Trying to include some CSS in Webpack is trowing an error

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

Look, my folder structure is like this:

- js

  - bundle.js
  - custom.js
- css

  - main.css
- style.css
- app.js
- webpack.config.js

I have my index linked to app.js, the problem is that the webpack config cannot compile the fils(apparently), here is what I mean to make things more clear:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './app.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
        { 
            test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ],
            include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/custom.js'),
            path.resolve(__dirname, 'js/owl-carousel.js'),
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
      }
};
```

It keeps trowing me an error of:
[image]

I have this on my app.js:

```
require('./style.css');
```

Am I wrong in somthing?

Answer (score 0):

use MiniCssExtractPlugin loader which will extract CSS  and write into new css file.

var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
add these in your webpack config:

```
rules: [

   {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use:  [  'style-loader', MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
    }
  ]
}
plugins: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'style.css',
  }),
```

Let me know you the issue still persists